# GUI runs with no errors but window doesn't appear

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Why i did not see my gui?

UI.py

```
from tkinter import *
BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#B1DDC6"
class FlashCard:
    def __int__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Flash Card")
        self.window.config(padx=50, pady=50, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR)
        self.window.mainloop()
```

main.py
from UI import FlashCard

FlashCard()

```
There is no error but gui not appear....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the FlashCard class, you typed `__int__` instead of `__init__`.

Change `def __int__(self):` to `def __init__(self):` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for answering. FYI: when you answer a question about a problem that was solely caused by a typo, you can flag it for closure since these questions _tend_ not to hold long-term value to other users. see flag -> needs improvement -> community-specific reasons -> not reproducible / caused by typo.